# How to precisely compare dates in rails using SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I didn't notice that until I run some rspecs and then the difference between some model creations is in order of milliseconds, because it's fast.

`created_at` of first model: 2014-10-29 23:26:54 UTC

`created_at` of second model: 2014-10-29 23:26:54 UTC

So, in my tests I want the second model to have `created_at` bigger than first, for example.
But it fails because the query ignores the milliseconds. Example: 2014-10-29 23:26:54 **.027824** UTC

Query that I am comparing dates:

```
model.where("created_at > #{another_model.created_at}")
```

Query output

```
SELECT FROM "models" WHERE created_at > '2014-10-29 23:26:54 UTC'
```

How do I precisely compare dates in Rails?
Thanks in advance